# JavaFX open Color Picker's Dialog on Custom Action Event

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, color-picker

I want to launch the Color Picker's Dialog window and get the selected color as output.
In my case I want this window to launch from clicking on a Rectangle object instead of the ColorPicker component.

I'm having trouble finding out what the class/method is for launching this window since all online resources just point me to ColorPicker examples which I want to avoid.
I tried checking the documentation without any luck so if you guys know how to help me I would be very grateful to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are asking how to make the color picker's popup appear without actually showing the color picker control. You need to have the color picker in the scene graph for it to work; however you can just make it invisible. Note that it will still be placed in the scene graph and its location will determine the location of the popup.

Here's a minimal example:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ColorPicker;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class HelloApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(100, 20, 200, 40);
        ColorPicker picker = new ColorPicker();
        picker.setVisible(false);
        Pane root = new Pane(rect, picker);
        rect.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        rect.fillProperty().bind(picker.valueProperty());
        rect.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
            // move the (invisible) color picker so the popup appears at the mouse:
            picker.relocate(e.getX(), e.getY() - picker.getHeight());
            picker.show();
        });
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 80);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

Here is how this looks at startup:

[image]

and here is the result of clicking on the rectangle:

[image]

Comment: Thanks you so much. Clever idea! I've been thinking to add the invisible ColorPicker but didn't know you could trigger it's dialog launch within code. This pretty much solves this question but now I'm faced with another issue. Would you know how I could delay execution of the code until after I choose the color from the window because right now it sets the rectangle's color before the color is chosen resulting in setting the previous chosen color every time.

Comment: @vperse I'm not sure I really understand what you are asking there (in particular about it setting the rectangle's color to the previous chosen color). But *"execution of the code until after I choose the color"*: can't you just put the code you want to execute in an `onAction` handler for the color picker?